# Get-SPWebTemplate doesn't show my template although it should

Tags: 2010, web-template

I have an issue, basically I've installed a web template and it was installed fine. When i try to create a website I see this template in the list and I can choose it and based on this template create a site.

But strangly enought, it maybe not registered well or I don't know why, but when I run powershell command Get-SPWebTemplate it is not there. I can also find it in the hive in SiteTemplate ...

I did clean the cache and did iisreset but still it is not there, although it works, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your webtemplate is probably not globally deployed

> [..]the documentation for Get-SPWebTemplate which
>   states “Displays all globally installed site templates that match the
>   given identity.” A sandboxed solution is not globally deployed, which
>   explains why the template couldn’t be found. [Source](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/powershell/get-spwebtemplate-not-displaying-custom-web-templates/)

Try this:

```
$web = get-spweb http://intranet
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "My Custom Template Name"}

#Uncomment to create web..
#New-SPWeb -Url "http://intranet/site1" -Name "Site 1" –Template $template
```

This will get it from available web templates instead, see more (and source of above script) [here](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/powershell/get-spwebtemplate-not-displaying-custom-web-templates/)

Comment: Ok, but how do I make it then globally deployed? Normally it should be globally deployd this web template. I deployed with the Install-SPSolution ... which normally is not really sandboxed

Comment: And just to note, this web template is note there either :(

Comment: Can you please add your feature information? Like scope, module etc

Comment: It is not really deployed by the feature, it is webtemplate from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1493

Comment: That is for WSS 3.0, not SP 2010.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't matter, it should work because it should be cross compatible ... and then again it works, i just dont understand why it doesn't register, before it did register, but i uninstalled solution and now when i install it doesn't work properly anymore

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to reactive a feature, that did not deactive when you uninstalled the solution and hence was not enabled correctly when you reinstalled. But it is hard to tell without knowing the inner workings of that specific solution

Comment: I checked the wsp file and there are not features that deploy this template, it just adds the template that is it, no feature related i think :/

Comment: Well there must be a feature that provisions the web template

Comment: I think when you deploy it, it just copies the ONET.xml to the sitetemplates folder in the hive. This is in the manifest file: <TemplateFile Location="SiteTemplates\projsing\xml\onet.xml"/>

Comment: Ok, it was solved, it seems the problem was, i had to restart the PowerShell command line window :)

Answer (score 1):

After trying to figure this out myself, I got the following that is dynamic. Hope this helps someone else that needs to use a template in multiple places.

```
$Siteurl = "http://intranet/site/custom"

$SPW = Get-SPweb $Siteurl

$template = $SPW.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "MyCustomTemplate"}

write-host "Applying custom template..."

$SPW.ApplyWebTemplate($template.Name)

$SPW.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may need to restart the server. I recently had a similar issue. However, I was migrating from SP 2010 to SP 2013. See here for more info: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-missingsitedefinition.html

Comment: I did restart Like everything, did IISRESET, cleared the cached, restarted timer ... everything many times :/ still nothing :(